# uploaded images are storing twice in database

Tags: php, database, image, file, mysqli

I'm working on a portfolio base website using php, when I'm uploading one or two images to database, that are storing in database but with twice, E.G, when I'm uploading one image named image.png, that stores twice like id=1 name=image.png, id=2 name=image.png.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRMIV.png)

code are added bellow Thanks for help..!

```html
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    if (count($_FILES['images']['name']) > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
            $date       = date('d-m-Y');
            $images     = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            $images_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
            if (empty($images)) {
                $error = "PLEASE SELECT AT LEAST ONE PHOTO.";
            } else {
                $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `portfolio` (`image_id`, `date`, `images`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$images', '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "')";
            }
            if (mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)) {
                $msg = "IMAGE UPLOADED TO YOUR PORTFOLIO";
            } else {
                $error = "IMAGE UPLOADING FAILED, PLEASE CHECK";
            }
            if (mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)) {
                move_uploaded_file($images_tmp, "../uploads/$images");
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: seems you execute the insert query twice

Comment: seems you are executing without understanding it

Comment: Solved because of add some un-needed if statement i the end. I just removed if statement and move_uploaded_file keep it out from if statement... if (mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)) {
                move_uploaded_file($images_tmp, "../uploads/$images");
            }

Answer (score 1):

May be it's because `$i` starts from value `0`, initialize $i = 1 in for loop

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++){
```

or make `count($_FILES['images']['name'])-1`

Answer (score 0):

1. Validate your input
2. Use PDO and prepared statements
3. your for-loop is looping over any and all contents of the $_FILES['images']['name'] array.

You can check the contents of your file upload using one of these few common debugging techniques:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_FILES);
var_export($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES);
```

And you should find it being something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => facepalm.jpg
            [1] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpn3FmFr
            [1] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 4
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15476
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php